# Updating documents on MongoDB suddenly stopped working (error: 8000, codeName: 'AtlasError') -- NodeJS driver, web app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodejs-server

I've had a NodeJS backend web app running perfectly with reading/writing to my MongoDB cluster for the last several weeks.  Today, I suddenly was getting errors when trying to update documents, yet I can still read/"find" documents without error.

My cluster did do the automatic update to MongoDB 6.0 recently, and I am using an old version of MongoDB on the NodeJS server (4.x), so I'm wondering if the issue is an incompatibility error (e.g. I'm using .findOneAndUpdate(), and I don't see that as an option in the NodeJS driver documentation -- they only use .updateOne().  However, I did switch to .updateOne() and it's still not working).

All I get for an error is the following:
{error: 8000, codeName: 'AtlasError'}

Most of what I can find has to do with MongoDB URI strings or update operations being incorrect, but I am still connecting and finding documents without a problem, and I'm trying the most basic version of .updateOne() without success.  (I still have read/write permissions on the MongoDB cluster as well)

I've also updated the server to the latest MongoDB version (5.X) and did any necessary updates to my syntax -- still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  I discovered it was simply due to reaching the maximum storage limit for the cluster I am on (M0).  I'm slightly over 512MB, which is the limit. That makes sense for still being able to read documents, but not insert/update.

Hopefully this can help someone solve this problem more quickly.  More descriptive MongoDB error messages would be nice :)